# Google Analytics shows different results for different time ranges

Tags: google-analytics

On one of my Google Analytics dashboard I have a widget that shows Users / New Users per country. When I open the dashboard with default date range 23 Jan - 22 Feb, the chart looks like that:

[image]

When I change the range to 25 Jan - 22 Feb it looks like that:

[image]

Is it a Google Analytics bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.   How is this question programing related?

Comment: That IS weird! It would be one thing if the scales where off if the two days that were removed from the last graphs where higher/lower than the other days. You are not adding a new filter or segment?

Comment: No, I'm just changing the date from the selector in upper right corner.